# Not able to catch an exception (Custom + Standard) from trigger

Tags: apex, exception

Please consider the below scenario:

1. I have an Application__c object.
2. I have a trigger on that (for simplicity, coded directly in trigger) which does one thing if the record name is Error then throws exception.

---

```
trigger ApplicationTrigger on Application__c (before insert, after update){

        if(trigger.new[0].Name == 'Error'){
            Application__c application;
            System.debug(application.Name);
        }
}
```

3. Now I am running below code:

   [image]

Now notice the catch statement is not executing, means system was not able to catch the exception. It came as the Fatal Error.

This is kind of a big issue where if there is null pointer or any other exception in trigger and exception handling code will not be able to do anything. Not even logging since it never reaches to catch block.

Let me know if you guys ever faced such situation and if yes what you did to make sure that it is properly caught.

Answer (score 8):

Try-catch spanning trigger transactions has been exceptionally unreliable for about a year now (if not longer). Some time ago, you used to be able to catch the correct type of exception (e.g. a NullPointerException would be just that), while I noticed either last year or early this year that any exception in a trigger would be converted to a DmlException instead, the original error lost. Now, it appears that any unhandled exception in a trigger immediately terminates the transaction, with the status code for the log showing that exception.

I'm going to check with some people over at salesforce.com and bring this up, see if it's an intentional change, or if there needs to be a bug logged. For now, the best advice I can offer you is this: do not allow exceptions to leave your current code context (e.g. a trigger) unless you're intentionally trying to terminate the transaction. Each code unit should be responsible for handling its own exceptions. If you need to report an error, always use the `addError` method to report the error back to the calling context.

This is really a best practice anyways. Exceptions should be exceptional (or ideally, never), and when/if they do happen, they should be handled as close to the source as possible. Always try to write code that won't generate exceptions, particularly NullPointerException, ListException, QueryException, MathException, and TypeException. All of these exceptions are easily avoidable and/or can be handled in the immediate vicinity of where they can occur.

---

Edit: I built a unit test for this, and the code worked as expected. Here's the trigger and unit test for context:

---

```
trigger q232645 on Lead (before insert) {
    if(Trigger.new[0].LastName == 'Exception') {
        Lead record;
        // This line here generates a NullPointerException...
        record.LastName = 'Test';
    }
}
```

---

```
@isTest class q232645Test {
    @isTest static void test() {
        try {
            insert new lead(LastName='Exception');
            System.assert(false, 'Should not reach here; trigger should throw exception.');
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('We should see this in the logs.');
            return;
        }
        System.assert(false, 'We should not get this far because of the return statement.');
    }
}
```

---

This unit test *passes*, despite the execute anonymous code not working. I'm convinced this is a bug, and I'll do my best to have some one look in to this for you.

---

Edit 2:

This is intended behavior, according to [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Exception-handling-between-class-and-Trigger&language=en_US&type=1) (thanks, @KiranMachhewar!). You must not allow exceptions to escape the trigger context.

Comment: But I am not completely aligned with the concept of handling exception as close to the source as possible, because here just for example I used null pointer. But in my application/code base I use Custom Exception heavily to stop the execution like when I don't find custom setting record or some data is required other wise there is no point in going further in code and such failure/exception situations code be anywhere in code. So exception makes most sense, but with the above problem looks like I am not able to log or properly notify to the user about the error.

Comment: Let me add more to this, I have a web service which is called from third party and I make sure that I give the error status code if the webservice code gets an exception and comes in catch block and I return the message also. Sometimes third party system could miss some values or sufficient data might not be present in my side only so I use Exceptions, it worked out really well, I had full confidence that no matter what (except uncatchable exceptions), I would be able to log the message and return the proper error but now as the control is not coming in catch, I am not respond error to other

Comment: @KiranMachhewar Exceptions should be used as sparingly as possible for performance reasons. There are times to use them, but definitely not to try and transmit data across a DML-transaction barrier.

Comment: -- continue 
other system and nor I am able to do my custom logging.
Again thank you for looking into this.

Comment: @KiranMachhewar Regardless, this looks like a bug, and even worse, your code works correctly in a unit test, which means something is amiss.

Comment: yes looks like a bug ( scary one ), I cannot trust my custom logs now :( (There will be none created in such cases)

Comment: @KiranMachhewar Again, you could choose to normal addError methods. This would be ideal. Just don't use the exception and you'll be fine.

Comment: Yes, I am going with that only. 
Still there are some code base which I reuse from batch and trigger so adding error in batch will not help. I think exception handling is a major topic to discuss here and much to learn in that. I trust your experience, I will study exception topic further deep. Again thank you for helping us all.

Comment: When I raised case with salesforce and talked to them they said its not a bug and it is implemented as per design and for this scenario they gave this workaround
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Exception-handling-between-class-and-Trigger&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: Only solution that I am thinking for such challenges is like wrapping the trigger in try catch and whatever exception comes catch it and add it via addError message then those exceptions will be converted to DMLExceptions (catchable by DML maker). But putting such boilerplate code in each and every trigger won't look good and explaining/convincing your team is another part.

Comment: @KiranMachhewar A better solution is to not write code that causes exceptions. The large majority of code for triggers can be written without any exception handling. For example, see an article [like this one](http://www.codinghell.ch/blog/2013/03/31/how-and-when-not-to-use-exceptions/). Exceptions should be exceptional, not a normal course of action. They hijack flow control, they are difficult to debug, they are slow/expensive. Exceptions should only ever cover a couple of lines of code.

Comment: agreed, for cases where you don't have enough data or config settings exceptions can be used not as a part of flow. But writing code which will not cause exceptions is not digestible to me atleast. On trigger anyone can write the code and potentially could break also, I do not have problem with that, once we know it's breaking we can fix that. But because of such fatal error you can't capture it, that's a bummer.

Comment: @KiranMachhewar Anyone could write code that does not break, either. For example, our two largest triggers have 2,000+ lines of code, and there are only 5 lines of those that are covered by try-catch (and those could actually be removed, now that I've reviewed them). Yes, this takes some experience, but it is possible to learn to write code that has minimal exception handling. It's all about knowing how each exception is generating, then coding defensively to avoid them.

Comment: @KiranMachhewar Also, fatal exceptions not caught in a trigger will be emailed to the developer. All of our fatal exceptions that do occur are in our inboxes. Just [Set up Apex exception email notifications](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000170712&language=en_US&type=1) and you'll have the same data you would have, conveniently in your email.

Comment: yes experience is the key, but sometimes managed package could also break over which you don't have control, I have seen managed packages from Salesforce breaking in production with null pointer exceptions. My say is that we cannot assume that we will write the perfect code which will never break, anyways it's matter of point of view. I like the idea of exceptions emails atleast this way we have some way to get errors ( I knew this, somewhere overlooked in memory palace to visit this )

Comment: @KiranMachhewar ISVs are responsible for handling their own exceptions--you should not have to. I've also said this elsewhere, it's almost always better to not try-catch and get an Apex exception email rather than use a try-catch incorrectly and hide bugs in production for months or years, later to discover bad data because of inappropriate handling. Most exceptions: null pointer exception, index out of bounds, invalid parameter, etc, can *all* be avoided. The rare exceptions are things like CalloutException, because of read timeouts, etc. Minimalist design is better.

Comment: I am against hiding errors or gulping exceptions. The intent is to make sure that errors are logged so that it becomes easy to check logs and solve the issue. Null pointer, index bounds etc such exceptions can be handled easily, but we cannot be aware about all the exceptions that could possibly happens and that is the reason for this error handling and capturing errors. Another use of custom log is to add some transactional related data which could be useful while debugging. Emails errors I believe only talks about the exception message and stack trace. Hiding bugs is upto us.

Comment: We can take proactive actions for the logs where errors occured, like marking such logs as error logs if control comes in catch block and then sending emails to respective team or subscribing to the report if the conditions are meeting.

Comment: @KiranMachhewar Yes, but to log the error you have to let the transaction complete (or use Platform Events), which might leave your data in an inconsistent state. Of course, I can't convince you of anything more than to do some more research on this. In my 11 years of Apex experience, I've never seen a case where a broad try-catch has been better than localized handling of errors. I'm simply suggesting that you might not have considered all the possible angles.

Comment: I also agree with localised handling of errors, just if someone has not done it means the broad try catch should kick in and do the logging or whatever handling that we have done. But here with this trigger exception behaviour broad try catch becomes useless. Broad try catch was like godfather who is now not supporting for this case :( . I will dig deeper but I think this is something which should be fixed in platform. Thank you for your attention and discussion on this.